# Получить доступ к файлу из assets

Tags: android

Есть класс `DBHelper` помощник унаследованный от `SQLiteOpenHelper`, в котором есть все методы для работы с БД (открытие, создание , обновление и т.д.). В папке `assets` есть файл обычный текстовый `db.txt`.

Можно ли в классе `DBHelper` получить доступ к файлу `db.txt`? Через `getAssets`() не получается.

Написал так, но не выводит ничего

```
public void getStringFromAssetFile(Context myContext)
{
    AssetManager am = myContext.getAssets();
    try {
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(am.open("db.txt")));
        String tmpStr;
        while ((tmpStr = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            try {
                System.out.println(tmpStr);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
protected String readFileInAssets(String name){

        String text = name;
        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = getAssets().open(text);
            int size = is.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str_data = new String(buffer);
        return str_data;
    }


TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText(readFileInAssets("db.txt",getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: В описании задачи написал как я пытаюсь сделать

Comment: `SQLiteOpenHelper` не имеет метода `getAssets()`

Answer (score 0):

1) База данных в Android хранится в формате bdName.**sqlite**
2) Сначала нужно создать БД скопировав данные из assets в корень самого приложения.

```
  public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        //ничего не делать - база уже есть
    } else {
        //вызывая этот метод создаем пустую базу, позже она будет перезаписана
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
        this.close();
    }
}

 private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        File file = new File(myPath);
        if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory())
            tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("Сheck", e.getMessage());
    }
    if (tempDB != null)
        tempDB.close();
    return tempDB != null ? true : false;
}

public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    try {
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open("databases/" + DATABASE_NAME);
        String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("СopyDatabase", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Это всё пишется в Вашем классе "DBHelper".